# How can change the sharing screen of google chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am developing a desktop app and there I need a sharing screen, I used ***google chrome default sharing screen*** but I want to **redesign it and want make it like skype sharing screen.**

How can I do this?

Chrome sharing screen'

[image]

Skype sharing screen

[image]

**

> **Google chrome Developers Please answer.**

**